How to pass a numeric variable, from inside a FOR loop, to a subroutine and retaining its value
I'm having a problem passing numeric variable, from inside a FOR loop, to a subroutine, and accessing its value.
I'm trying to pass some numeric values to a subroutine, but I'm getting strange results. The value, when passed via CALL does not get updated.
I've even tried to enabledelayedexpansion, but hasn't changed anything. I usually avoid enabling delayed expansion because screws some file names and folders containing & and (). CALLing a subroutine solves the problem. But in this particular case, can't seem to find an answer.
Following is the troubled code:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
CLS
SET /A Index=1
FOR /L %%I IN (1, 1, 11) DO (
   CALL :Params %Index% %%I
   CALL SET /A Index+=1
)
PAUSE
EXIT

:Params
ECHO %1 %2
EXIT /B


Run results:
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 10
1 11
Press any key to continue . . .

Any thoughts?
Regards...
What I am doing right now to circumvent this behaviour, it to echo the %Index% var directly from subroutine (ECHO %INDEX% %2)

I don't see a reason for CALL SET /A Index+=1 over Set /A Index += 1, just remove the unnecessary CALL. Then change CALL :Params %Index% %%I to Call :Params %%Index%% %%I.

Did as you suggested, but when run with your modifications, the output becomes : 1ndex 1
2ndex 2
3ndex 3
4ndex 4
5ndex 5
6ndex 6
7ndex 7
8ndex 8
9ndex 9
10ndex 10
11ndex 11
Press any key to continue . . .
The CALL SET is to expand the variable immediatelly...

Pretty sure you need to use delayed expansion for the index variable.

Yes, it does work. Is it the only way? It really screws up file names and folder names wit ampersand and parenthesis... Usually CALLing a soutine, expands immediatelly...

You just need to change the  %%I  letter of the FOR command by any other letter... OR change your Index  variable with an initial letter different than I

You nailed it! I would have never guessed it! Thank you very much for your insight.

The metavariable %%I is processed first,  your %%Index%% variable starts with %%I hence the result in the comments. You stated that delayedexpansion also did not work, simply that is because you did not do CALL :Params !Index! %%I where ! indicates the variables to expand.

Modify SET /A Index=1 to SET Index=1. See for the reason: Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line? Then modify the entire FOR loop to the single line FOR /L %%I IN (1, 1, 11) DO CALL :Params %%I. Replace EXIT by EXIT /B. Replace below :Params the command line ECHO %1 %2 by ECHO %Index% %1 and insert next SET /A Index+=1 before the final EXIT /B whereby I would use as last line GOTO :EOF for making it easier to see where the subroutine and where the batch processing ends.

There is absolutely no need to increment the value of the environment variable Index inside the FOR loop and pass its current value as argument to the subroutine :Params. The command lines in the subroutine can access all environment variables defined in main code and can modify them as well. In fact there are use cases where a string like a directory/file name must be assigned to an environment variable in a FOR loop which is referenced in a subroutine because of passing the string as argument to the subroutine does not work.

A file/folder name with % cannot be passed correct to a subroutine as argument because of double parsing caused by CALL. If there is a file with name Development & Test 100% (!).txt in current directory and there is used in a batch file for %%I in (*.txt) do call :DisplayName "%%I" and below :DisplayName the command line echo File name: %1, there is output File name: "Development & Test 100 (!).txt". The character % is missing in file name. The usage of for %%I in (*.txt) do set "FileName=%%I" & call :DisplayName with echo File name: "%FileName%" solves the problem.
